# How to pass an external id to a domain filter

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I have a Many2One field accepting a product in my model, but I want to limit this field to a specific product template, using the said template external id (The XML id).

I've try this without success:

```
#This piece of code doesn't work
the_product = fields.Many2one('product.product', 
                  domain = [('product_tmpl_id','=', "ref('the_package.the_external_id')")])
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to use a function that returns the filters parameters. That way, we have access to the `self` variable in the body of the function, and therefore, we can use it to search specific external ids.

```
@api.model
def _get_domain(self):
    # We have access to self.env in this context.
    ids = self.env.ref('the_package.the_external_id').ids
    return [('product_tmpl_id','=', ids)]


the_field = fields.Many2one('product.product',
                             required=False, 
                             domain = _get_picking_product_domain)
```

Answer (score 0):

The above solution does does not work.

Error :

ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'model_name'

But try this:

You don't have to insert domain in your field :

```
@api.onchange('field_a')
def fiel_change(self):
    dom['field_a'] = [(*)] #* type your domain  
    return {'domain':dom}
```